# Как можно реализовать на WPF флажок,который меняет цвет с одного на другой при нажатии?

Tags: c#, wpf

Необходимо реализовать на WPF флажок,который меняет цвет с одного на другой при нажатии,как,например, checkbox?
Пример того,что я хочу видеть в результате.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот картинки флажков

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: флажок уже нарисовали?

Comment: @FoggyFinder  Нет.

Comment: Тогда значит у вас два вопроса?

Comment: @FoggyFinder Нет,мне просто нужен пример,как это реализовывать,а если говорить про отрисовку картинки флажка,то достаточно сказать размеры.

Comment: @FoggyFinder  Я добавил картинки флажков.

Comment: Переопределите шаблон для CheckBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да,действительно.эту проблема решается просто переопределением шаблона для CheckBox.

```
<Window x:Class="Email_client.View.Email"       
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Email_client.Model"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Email_client.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Email" Height="526.684" Width="720.326">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="styleCustomCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image x:Name="imageCheckBox" Source="C:\flag(blue).png" Width="15" Height="15" Margin="5" />
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="imageCheckBox" Property="Source" Value="C:\flag(white).png" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>



         <Grid>                  
    <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Style="{StaticResource styleCustomCheckBox}" Content="I am a custom checkbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

а я как-то нашел 
http://www.wpfhelper.com/index.php/component/easytagcloud/89-module/CheckBox

там и шаблон есть 
а можно так

```
<Style x:Key="CheckedStyleCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
      Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
      Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <ImageBrush x:Key="SwitchBrushOf" ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Images/button_cancel.png" />
                    <ImageBrush x:Key="SwitchBrushOn" ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Images/button_ok.png" />
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <BulletDecorator Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Border Width="32" Height="30" Name="Border" Background="{StaticResource SwitchBrushOf}" Cursor="Hand">
                                <Border.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"/>
                                </Border.Effect>
                            </Border>
                            <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="2" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                </BulletDecorator>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True" >
                        <Trigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"  Value="{StaticResource SwitchBrushOn}"/>
                        </Trigger.Setters>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Trigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SwitchBrushOf}"/>
                        </Trigger.Setters>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

используем картинки из ресурсов